# Splitting Link using RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex, url

i want to find category from the link. I am breaking the link into array using Regex like this.

```
string input = link;
string pattern = "/";            // Split on hyphens 

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
foreach (string match in substrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
}
```

My links are:

```
http://www.example.com/lifestyle/food/a93ypt9-1227277841603?from=public_atom
http://www.example.com/sports/scoccer/accept9-1227277841603?from=public_atom
```

Whereas categories of the above links

```
lifestyle
sports
```

I am splitting the link on hyphens and finding out my category but is there any better way to accomplish my task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you think you need to use regular expressions?  The `Uri` class can parse and interpret the paths for you.  You can get direct access to the `Segments`.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.link.com/lifestyle/food/a93ypt9-1227277841603?from=public_atom");
uri.Segments; // [ "/", "lifestyle/", "food/", "a93ypt9-1227277841603" ]
```

Comment: That's why he posted, he was looking for something other than regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you need Regex pattern (exactly for your links), try this:

```
\/{1,2}
```

or

```
\/{1,2}|\?{1}
```

for splitting parametres too

see [.net regex tester](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.split?p=XC97MSwyfXxcP3sxfQ%3D%3D&t=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9saWZlc3R5bGUvZm9vZC9hOTN5cHQ5LTEyMjcyNzc4NDE2MDM%2FZnJvbT1wdWJsaWNfYXRvbQ%3D%3D)